# How to get this UI output in printout?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am working on WPF application.Here i have to work on some print formats.To solve paging issue for print i am using the following code :

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a PrintDialog
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        
        // Create a FlowDocument dynamically.
        FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocument();
        doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
        doc.PageHeight = printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight;
        doc.PageWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth;
        // Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument
        IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
        // Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer
        printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing."); 

    }
```

and

```
private FlowDocument CreateFlowDocument()
    {

        // Create a FlowDocument
        FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
        int i = 0;
        while (i <2)
        {
            // Create first Paragraph
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
            MyUserControl comp = new MyUserControl ();
            p1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(79, 129, 189));
            p1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            p1.Inlines.Add(comp); 
            // Add Paragraph to Section
            doc.Blocks.Add(p1);
            // Add Section to FlowDocument
            //doc.Blocks.Add(sec);
            i++;
        }
     
        return doc;

    }
```

this code works fine for me.

**Problem :**

I just have problem with UI which i am getting using this code.

This is the print which i am getting now on paper :

[image]

and this is the print which i require on paper:

[image]

Please provide some idea and code so that i can clear this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well logic says that you should add that static part with full width before running that loop and after that add dynamic parts in that loop one by one, But I didn't see your static part there have you missed posting something ?

Comment: ohh.. yes static part is missed there.It is simple table with columns.